# ColdFusion query dropdownlist

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to populate a dropdown list with query results? For example with this output: `Peps Company - AL` ie (Company and State) separated with a hyphen.

Edit: Sorry for leaving out code. There is only one datasource.

```
<cfquery name="CompanyInfo" datasource=>
SELECT  company, state
FROM    clients
WHERE   serv_billing = 1 
AND     status = 'Active' 
ORDER BY Company
</cfquery>


<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="nextpage.cfm">
    <SELECT name="company">
      <CFOUTPUT QUERY="CompanyInfo">
        <OPTION value="#CompanyInfo.company#">#CompanyInfo.company# - #CompanyInfo.state#</OPTION>
      </CFOUTPUT>
    </SELECT>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit Company">
</FORM>
```

Would this code give me the desired format for the dropdown list items ie `Peps - AL`?

?

Comment: Please provide some sample data from your two queries, as well as a sample of the HTML markup you'd like to see produced.

Comment: Concur with @Jake Feasel, more information regarding this question needs to be specified in the description, such as the issue noted below on *why* there is a need to separate them into two different queries (ie. a dependency on two DSNs)

Comment: There is still the question of *why* the need for two queries. I do not see a second query in the code above.

Comment: sorry. I originally thought it was two datasources, but it turns out to be only one.

Comment: It looks to me like you're saying "two queries" but you meant "two columns".  Is that right?

Comment: You are correct. That would be my mistake.

Comment: Two columns would be correct.

Comment: Did you try it out? What's the problem?

Comment: ColdFusion (without space) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. This code will do precisely that.

Does it not work? Do you have a problem with it, or..? I find it strange that you didn't simply try it out because you already seem to have the code to do what you want to do.

Comment: I was just making sure. It will be a little while before I can test it out.

Comment: Wow, writing code without being able to test it is pretty brave. :) - You can download a development version of ColdFusion for free to run it on your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

[Seybsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982002/seybsen)'s answer is technically correct, however, I would compel you to follow best practices and perform a single loop, rather than iterative returns to the database on each row result of the main query:

```
<CFQUERY name="qCompanies" datasource="yourdsn">
  SELECT companies.id, companies.company, states.state_code
  FROM companies
  INNER JOIN states ON (companies.state_id = states.state_id)
</CFQUERY>

<SELECT name="company">
  <CFOUTPUT QUERY="qCompanies">
    <OPTION value="#qCompanies.id#">#qCompanies.company# - #qCompanies.state_code#</OPTION>
  </CFOUTPUT>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with cfloop like this:

```
 <cfquery name="CompanyInfo" datasource="yourdsn">
  SELECT company, state
  FROM clients
  WHERE serv_billing = 1 AND status = 'Active' 
  Order by Company
</cfquery>

<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="nextpage.cfm">
  <SELECT name="company">
    <CFLOOP QUERY="CompanyInfo">
       <OPTION value="#CompanyInfo.company#">#CompanyInfo.company# - #CompanyInfo.state#</OPTION>
    </CFLOOP>
 </SELECT>
 <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit Company">
</FORM>
```

Comment: No, this is a case where you need `cfoutput`. Otherwise you are just populating the list with the variable names, not their values.